# Azure App Services User Claims AAD Missing ObjectId

Tags: azure, active-directory

I'm in the process of migrating from Azure Mobile Services to App Services and currently struggling to find the AAD User objectidentifier with the new OWIN authentication configured in `Startup.MobileApp.cs`. `

```
MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();
                        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MS_AadClientID"]},
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MS_AadTenants"]
                });
```

Previously I was looking for:

```
claim.Type.Contains("urn:microsoft:credentials")
```

but none of the Claims on the `User.Identity` provide an objectidentifier.
[Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XkPl.png)

The objectidentifier is available on `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`.

```
{"typ":"http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/identity\/claims\/objectidentifier",
"val":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Does anybody know if it's possible to access the value without making a call to the URL?

Thanks,

Viv

Comment: Did you mean that you want to get the value about **oid** claim in the Azure AD token? If I understood correctly, we are able to get this value directly through **ClaimsPrincipal class**. Here is the code `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Fei Xue. I've added the available claims to the post. I get the same options whether I access through the User or ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: @fei, is there an extension class which provides the AAD objectidentifer claim? It's missing from the list I have available.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through both the iOS and [.NET server code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/33e13128544c917e00f9bff9813059b4cdf37057/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/Extensions/IPrincipalExtensions.cs), I found a method in the  `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication IPrincipalExtensions` class.

by making a call to                `user.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(request);`
you can get the `AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials.ObjectId`.

Be warned though as this is not available if you authenticate directly through the webservice.